# AutoML table on GCP Vertex AI model identification

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, automl

I am using GCP's Vertex AI automl table for a classification problem and I would like to know if/how can I retrieve the actual model and architecture that is used.

Tried something like this on jupyter notebook

```
import tensorflow as tf

model_uri = 'gs://works_user/1249798924374376448-3739934513493442560/dataflow_staging/evaluation-1249798924374376448-3739934513493442560-evaluation-run.1693304104.015865/pipeline.pb'

# Load the model
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_uri, compile=False)

# Display model summary
loaded_model.summary()

# Display layer weights
for layer in loaded_model.layers:
    if hasattr(layer, 'get_weights'):
        weights = layer.get_weights()
        if weights:
            print(f'Layer {layer.name}:')
            for i, w in enumerate(weights):
                print(f'  Weight {i + 1}: {w.shape}')
```

I got this error:

```
OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)
```